# Tolerance interval and significant probability

Tags: probability, hypothesis-testing, statistical-significance, tolerance-interval

Let's take for simplicity an *iid* sample from a Gaussian random variable $Y \sim \mathcal{N}(\mu, \sigma^2)$. Let $y_0 \in \mathbb{R}$. The $(1-\alpha, p)$-bound of the lower one-sided (i.e. right-sided) tolerance interval is a $(1-\alpha)$-lower confidence bound of the quantile $q_p$ of the normal distribution $\mathcal{N}(\mu, \sigma^2)$. Therefore, if this tolerance bound is higher than $y_0$, one can say that the exceedance probability $\Pr(Y > y_0)$ is $\alpha$-significantly higher than $p$.

Now take two real numbers $y_1 < y_2$. If the two-sided $(1-\alpha,p)$-tolerance interval falls inside the interval $[y_1, y_2]$, does it make sense to say that the probability $\Pr\bigl(Y \in [y_1, y_2]\bigr)$ is significantly higher than $p$ at the $\alpha$ level?

Comment: What happens as $y_1$ approaches arbitrarily close to $y_2$?  The probability in question ought to grow vanishingly small.  Any procedure that concludes this probability is significantly greater than any given positive $p$ would be awfully suspect!

Comment: @whuber I'm not comfortable with this question (that's why I ask it ^^) but I don't follow your reasoning. If the interval $[y_1,y_2]$ is small, and if the tolerance interval falls inside it, that means that the (estimate of the) standard deviation is small, and then the probability is not small.

Comment: I don't follow your conclusion, and perhaps that amounts to not understanding what you mean by "the two-sided tolerance interval." Usually that is understood to be a confidence interval for the quantile $q_p$.  Thus, you cannot draw *any* conclusion about the SD of $Y$: like most confidence intervals, that one shrinks down to zero as the amount of data grows, independently of whatever value the SD of $Y$ might be (even if the SD is infinite!).

Comment: A lower (upper) tolerance limit is a lower (upper) confidence bound about the quantile. But this is not true for the two-sided tolerance interval (usually called the "tolerance interval", shortly).

Comment: Why don't you follow my conclusion ? The length of the tolerance interval is $2k\hat\sigma$. So I simply say that $\hat\sigma$ is small if this interval is contained in a small interval.

Comment: Please clarify what you mean by "tolerance interval."  It does not seem to correspond to the definitions I am familiar with, such the one in Hahn & Meeker, *Statistical Intervals.*  If you think we're in agreement that it's a confidence interval for a quantile, you might consider how $k$ is computed and note that it shrinks to zero as the sample size grows large.

Comment: I take the usual definition, the one given page 4 [here](http://media.wiley.com/product_data/excerpt/68/04703802/0470380268.pdf). And no, the [k(2)-factor](http://www.world-class-quality.com/images/download/20081104091802_tolerance%20factor%20tables%20normal%20dist%20oct08.pdf) does not go to $0$ as the sample size goes to infinity, because the tolerance interval goes to the $100p\%$-dispersion interval.

Comment: Are you perhaps thinking of a *prediction* interval?  Otherwise, since a tolerance interval is a confidence interval, you are denying the impossibility of the interval converging to the true value as more data are collected--which would be a very strange situation. The table makes it look like you might be trying to construct a two-sided tolerance interval for the *central portion* of a distribution rather than a two-sided tolerance interval for a single quantile--but at present your post appears to state just the opposite.

Comment: Yes, "the central portion", as you say. The two-sided tolerance interval has form $\bar y \pm k_2\hat\sigma$. My post does not state the opposite. The beginning of my post is about the lower/upper tolerance limit (which is a lower/upper confidence limit about the quantile), not with the two-sided tolerance interval.

Comment: OK, then: (1) to avoid confusion it would be better to describe the two-sided TI. (2) Let the TI be $[l,u]\subset [y_1,y_2]$.  By the very definition of the TI, $\Pr(Y\in [y_1,y_2]) \ge\Pr(Y\in[l,u]) \ge p$ with probability at least $1-\alpha$. Doesn't that completely answer the question?

Comment: @whuber I think there's something wrong in your claim because you obtain the inequality $\Pr(Y\in[y_1,y_2]) \geq p$ with a certain probability, while there is no random variable in this inequality. I've just posted an answer. I would be grateful if you can check it.

Comment: I apologize that the brevity required of comments did not allow me the luxury of a more extended explanation.  The TI itself is a *random interval*: the quantities $l$ and $u$ are both random.  $\Pr(Y\in[l,u])$ is intended to be evaluated over $Y$, and then the "probability at least $1-\alpha$" is with respect to the joint distribution of $(l,u)$.

Comment: @whuber Yes I know. But your inequality *implies* $\Pr(Y\in[y_1,y_2]) \geq p$. Isn't it weird? Perhaps I'm just puzzled...

Answer (score 2):

No this is not true.

## One-sided case

> Therefore, if this tolerance bound is higher than $y_0$, one can say
>   that the exceedance probability $\Pr(Y > y_0)$ is
>   $\alpha$-significantly higher than $p$.

Let's check this claim with the help of simulations. We simulate $Y_i \sim_{\text{iid}} \mathcal{N}(0,1)$, we take $y_0=1$, and we take the lower tolerance bound with coverage $p=\Pr(Y_i>y_0)$. Then the probability that the lower tolerance bound is higher than $y_0$ should be $\alpha$.

```
y0 <- 1
p <- 1-pnorm(y0)
nsims <- 200000
n <- 10
k <- tolerance::K.factor(n, alpha=0.05, P=p, side=1)
test <- logical(nsims)
for(i in 1:nsims){ 
  Y <- rnorm(n)
  bound <- mean(Y) - k*sd(Y)
  test[i] <- bound > y0
}
```

This is confirmed by the simulations:

```
> mean(test)
[1] 0.049805
```

## Two-sided case

> Now take two real numbers $y_1 < y_2$. If the two-sided
>   $(1-\alpha,p)$-tolerance interval falls inside the interval 
>   $[y_1,y_2]$, does it make sense to say that the probability 
>   $\Pr\bigl(Y \in [y_1, y_2]\bigr)$ is significantly higher than $p$ at the 
>   $\alpha$ level?

Let's check with simulations that this is not true. As for the one-sided case, if we take $p = \Pr\bigl(Y_i \in [y_1, y_2]\bigr)$, then the probability that the two-sided $(1-\alpha,p)$-tolerance interval falls inside the interval $[y_1,y_2]$ should be $\alpha$ if the claim were true.

```
y1 <- -1; y2 <- 2
p <- pnorm(y2)-pnorm(y1)
nsims <- 200000
n <- 10
k <- tolerance::K.factor(n, alpha=0.05, P=p, side=2, method="EXACT")
test <- logical(nsims)
for(i in 1:nsims){ 
  Y <- rnorm(n)
  bounds <- mean(Y) + k*c(-1,1)*sd(Y)
  test[i] <- bounds[1] > y1 && bounds[2] < y2
}
```

This is not confirmed:

```
> mean(test)
[1] 0.01193
```